# Is Consul services discovery supported in Spring Cloud Gateway MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I do not seem to find references to automatic discovery of Consul services for the project Spring Cloud Gateway MVC https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc.html

I see that in Spring Cloud Gateway based on Webflux there is that support, though. I was wondering if it was me not being able to see it for MVC or if Spring Cloud Gateway MVC still lacks support for this.

Comment: It supports any load balanced URI, but it won't automatically create routes based on service discovery